# How to use Java lambda Expressions for regular expressions

Tags: java, selenium, lambda, java-8

In below code i am getting all elements from the list and splitting the text after `"("`.

```
for (WebElement element : measureKeys) {
    String[] measure = element.getText().split("\\(");
    testing.add(measure[0])
}
```

How to use lambdas for above code

Comment: Do you mean stream?

Comment: why do you want to change it?

Comment: Yes using streams

Comment: To be honest: This code looks good as it it. I'm sure using ``stream()`` and ``collect()`` will make this more readable.

Answer (score 8):

You could essentially turn the body of the loop to a lambda expression and collect the the results

```
List<String> testing = 
    measureKeys.stream()
               .map(e -> element.getText().split("\\(")[0])
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is ,

```
List<String> list= Pattern.compile("\\(")
                      .splitAsStream(measureKeys)
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<String> measureKeys = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
    measureKeys.forEach(element -> a.add(element.split("\\(")[0]));
```

Is that your wish ?